# How to change number values in PHP when radio button is check or click

Tags: php, javascript

I have 4 rows in a table.

Each row has 4 radio buttons.

Each radio buttons has value number [1, 2, 3, 4]

When user selects one of the radio buttons, it automatically prints the value in each row. Then I take each value and total them at the bottom of the table.

I'm guessing it can be done with javascript? But how?

Here's a sample PHP code for the row:

```
<input type="radio" name="a" value="1" <?php if($row['a'] == '1'){echo "checked";} ?>/>
```

I want to print out the value at the end of each row. Then total the each row's value at the bottom of the table.

Also, here's my php code to total all rows.

> ```
>                                   $total = $a + $b + $c + $d;
>
>                                   echo $total;
>                               ?>
> ```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, but you should provide your buttons' and table's code and show where you're stuck so far

Comment: Can you provide your PHP code specifically? thanks!

Comment: I just updated the question :) Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Though I can't post any code at the moment (dehabilitating numeric keypad),</strike> the general method to dynamically update content dependent on a backend is to activate an AJAX call (or page refresh) whenever a checkbox's state is changed. The new state and/or unique parameters will be sent to your server, which will then `echo` (as per your request) out the new view.

From the information you've provided, it is difficult to determine whether the radio buttons dependend on any special backend model (database information).

If they are not, then we will assume that the checkboxes have unique IDs, prefixed with `chk_`, and that the text box you want to output the value to is called `out`. We will also assume that you are using jQuery.

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var e = $('#chk' + i);
    if (e.is(':checked'))
    {
        total += parseInt(e.val());
    }
}
$("#out").text(total);
```

EDIT: After the edit of your original post, this code is still valid. However, if you name your checkbox `a` like you have, you will need to revise the `for` loop in the above code. You may be able to loop through all radio buttons, or radio buttons inside a certain HTML element. The implementation is up to you.

Comment: is this a javascript code? I just updated my question with how I got my total for each row. How can I implement your code?

Comment: @Arnold: Yes, that is Javascript code that you embed into your HTML output. Note that the above is dependent on jQuery, a free, open source Javascript "plugin".

Answer (score 0):

All the calculations should made on client side as per your scenario. So in this case JavaScript will do the work.

Below code will calculate each row as per radio selection and also calculate total of all selections.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--

        function calculateRow(val1, val2)
        {
            var total = 0;
            var ctr=1;
            var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
            document.getElementById('selectedValue_'+val2).innerHTML = val1.value;
            for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
            {
                divId = divs[i].id.substring(0,14);
                if(divId == 'selectedValue_')
                {
                    total += parseInt(document.getElementById('selectedValue_'+ctr).innerHTML);
                    ctr++;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
        }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frmScore">
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>Select</td>
<td>Score</td>
</tr>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type='radio' value='1' name='test{$i}' onclick='calculateRow(this,{$i})'>
        <input type='radio' value='2' name='test{$i}' onclick='calculateRow(this,{$i})'>
        <input type='radio' value='3' name='test{$i}' onclick='calculateRow(this,{$i})'>
        <input type='radio' value='4' name='test{$i}' onclick='calculateRow(this,{$i})'>
        </td>
        <td><div id='selectedValue_{$i}'>0</div></td>
    </tr>";
}
?>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><div id='total'></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!!!